# python 3.5 tkinter gui program

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

This is my first question....i want to help that how this code exactly works...

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def left(event):
    print("LEFT")

def middle(event):
    print("MIDDLE")

def right(event):
    print("RIGHT")

def key(event):
    print("You pressed the key:", repr(event.char))

def callback(event):
    f1.focus_set()
    print("clicked at", event.x, event.y)

f1 = Frame(root, width=300, height=300, bg="cyan")
f1.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
f1.bind("<Button-2>", middle)
f1.bind("<Button-3>", right)
f1.bind("<Key>",key)
f1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What specifically do you have trouble understanding about the code?

Comment: def callback(event):
    f1.focus_set()
    print ("clicked at", event.x, event.y)

Comment: that section im not understand

Comment: Use `help(Frame.focus_set)` to access the docs for the method. As the method describes, the focus is set to the frame. It helps to comment out lines to see what it affects as well. You'll notice that with it, key presses are registered after left clicking the frame.

Comment: ohkk Thanks......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It basically creates a frame, which has the following actions associated:

- Left click with the mouse ("Button-1"): it focuses on the frame and prints on the console the clicked location ('x' and 'y'). The top left corner will say "clicked at 0,0" while the bottom right corner "clicked at 300,300". If you enlarge the frame (by changing 'height' and 'width'), you will have more pixels to click.
- Middle click ("Button-2"): It prints the message of the function 'middle'.
- Right click ("Button-3"): It prints the message of the function 'right'.
- Keyboard event ("Key"): It prints the key that has been pressed in the keyboard.

Comment: can u tell me what is focus_set()...and thank you so much

Comment: focus_set() is a method to focus on a certain widget (in this case a frame).   When you have a lot of widgets, it is useful to move the focus to the widget that you want. Without it, the keyboard event does not work properly.